# Importing Python package - "ImportError: No module named..."

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I know there are a lot of questions about "ImportError: No module named..." but they ususally seem to boil down to no `__init__.py` file or the package directory not in `$PYTHONPATH`. I've checked both of those issues and my issue is not down to them.

I have a project which contains protocol buffer definitions. There's a makefile which generates the source as Python, Java or Go. There's a `setup.py` file which executes `make python`. I've run `pip install -e .` in this directory which generates the source files as expected.

I then have a separate project where I'm trying to use the generated protobufs.

Let me illustrate my projects:

```
myproject/
├── module
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── module.py
└── main.py

myprotos/
├── Makefile
├── __init__.py
├── my.proto
├── my_pb2.py (generated by the makefile on install)
├── myprotos.egg-info (generated by setup.py)
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
└── setup.py
```

The source of `setup.py` is pretty simple:

```python
import subprocess
import sys

from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install

class Install(install):
    """Customized setuptools install command - builds protos on install."""
    def run(self):
        protoc_command = ["make", "python"]
        if subprocess.call(protoc_command) != 0:
            sys.exit(-1)
        install.run(self)


setup(
    name='myprotos',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='',
    install_requires=[],
    cmdclass={
        'install': Install,
    }
)
```

The `__init__.py` in `myprotos` simply contains:

```python
import my_pb2
```

And then the contents of `myproject/main.py` is:

```python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/myprotos')

import myprotos
```

Running this code, `python main.py` outputs:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    import myprotos
ImportError: No module named myprotos
```

What have I missed here? It seems like this should work but I clearly haven't understood something crucial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say you have below structure :

```
demo_proj
    |
    myproject/
    ├── module
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── module.py
    └── main.py

    myprotos/
    ├── Makefile
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── my.proto
    ├── my_pb2.py
    ├── myprotos.egg-info
    │   ├── PKG-INFO
    │   ├── SOURCES.txt
    │   ├── dependency_links.txt
    │   └── top_level.txt
    └── setup.py
```

**Code in main.py:**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/demo_proj')

import myprotos
```

Comment: @Josh - Can you please give the complete traceback? Will help me to understand.